# Windows - only the first entry of PATH-environment variable can be found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

The following problem with my PATH-environment variable I have for some time, and it's become untolerable annoying so I would appreciate help a lot.

The following is the content of my system environment variables, which is also the output of echo %PATH% on cmd-exe.

C:\MinGW\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin; C:\msys\1.0\bin; C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\bin; C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin; %JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2_HOME%\bin; C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\miktex\bin; C:\Program Files\PDF Split And Merge Basic\bin; C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin

The thing is now, that only the first entry of this can be used, i.e the command "g++" (which is in C:\MinGW\bin ) can be found, but already the command "cl" (which is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin) can't be found, and all subsequent commands also not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try:
1) Remove the spaces from the path after each semicolon and see if this helps.
2) Did you make sure you're running PowerShell/Command Prompt in Administrator mode?
3) Did you make it System or User Variables? I'm not sure if there is a major difference in practice, but hey, try anything if you're lost.

Comment: The spaces cause the problem, you'll have to remove them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MinGW and JDK mutually disable each other's executables in path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723259/mingw-and-jdk-mutually-disable-each-others-executables-in-path)