# MinGW and JDK mutually disable each other's executables in path

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables, mingw

All following settings are in system variables only (my user variables don't include either JDK or MinGW addresses). I have a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set up like this: 
`JAVA_HOME`  -  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`

(this produces the same behavior as if I had written the address of jdk to the path)

When my path variable begins with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; C:\MinGW\bin; ...` I get correct `javac` access in cmd, but neither `gcc` nor `g++` works.
Usual error message:

> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

And when my path variable begins with `C:\MinGW\bin; %JAVA_HOME%\bin; ...` I get working `gcc` commands but now `javac` is unrecognized...

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

How can I solve this problem?

(I'm trying to set up an environment for Eclipse to develop to Android with cocos2d-x, I use MinGW v4.8.1, JDK 1.8 x64 and Win v8.1 x64)

---

My full path looks like this:

%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\

Where javapath indirectly points to JRE exe's.

Edit:
jdk1.7.0_79 x64 produces the same result (I'm sticking with 1.7 from now on)

Edit:
I reinstalled mingw, nothing changed. If the jdk address precedes the mingw address, all mingw executables become unreachable, vica-versa, this is killing me :(

I tried many variations, the path to JRE must precede the path to MinGW, otherwise I can't even call "java" from cmd, however it doesn't disable MinGW's exe's like the JDK does.

So this variation for example still hides all of MinGW exe's from The Path:
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. My.. God... [Windows - only the first entry of PATH-environment variable can be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093118/windows-only-the-first-entry-of-path-environment-variable-can-be-found?rq=1)

**THE SPACES!!! DON'T PUT SPACE AFTER A SEMICOLON!!**

(Whoever created environment variable editing UI (especially the parsing), along with MSVS's inclusion/linkage editing, should be *CENSORED*)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the g++ and javac from the MinGW bash prompt or Windows CMD ?

Assuming it from Windows CMD since you are changing the path there.. everything looks alright to me.  Is the g++ available in C:\MinGW\bin ?  Also, once you update the PATH, you have to open a new CMD window to make the updated path effective.

Comment: I'm using windows cmd, and I always reopen the cmd windows. And yes all the exe's are correctly in this folder C:\MinGW\bin. It all works too if I remove the address to the jdk preceding it.